# how to use exec() without any parameter?

Tags: linux, kernel, call, system

I wanna run "ls" command by exec(), and my code is exec("/bin/ls", NULL) but I got an text shows "A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call." If I add "all" as parameter it woks.    exec("/bin/ls","all",NULL)

however, when I use exec("/bin/ps", NULL), it works properly. So could you help me to figure out whats wrong with my program?

BTW: I use execl()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>             //required for fork()
#include <sys/types.h>          //required for wait()
#include <sys/wait.h>           //required for wait()

using namespace std;

int main(){
        string cmd="";
        string cmdpath="/bin/";
        cout<<endl<<getcwd(NULL,0)<<" >> ";
        cin>>cmd;
        cout<<endl;
        string cmdCmdpath = cmdpath+cmd;
        const char* charcmd = cmdCmdpath.c_str();

        int x = fork();
        if(x!=0){
                cout<<"The command "<<cmd<<" is running"<<endl;
                wait(NULL);
                cout<<"Im parent!"<<endl;
        }else if (x==0){
                cout<<"Im child!"<<endl;
                execl(charcmd,NULL);
                cout<<"Child done"<<endl;
        }

}
```

Comment: Where's your program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can the execve system call run "/bin/sh" without any argv arguments, but not "/bin/ls"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673765/why-can-the-execve-system-call-run-bin-sh-without-any-argv-arguments-but-not)

Answer (score 2):

Carefully read desctiption of [execl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec):

> The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.

It means, that second the `execl` parameter should be path, referred to the same file as the first one. Usually, the first and second parameters are same:

```
execl(charcmd, charcmd, NULL);
```